# Forward HTTP Request with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I am implementing a 'Validation' service where I would like to validate following HTTP request properties:

- Request Header
- Request Body
- Query Parameters
- URL Parameters

Once the above properties are validated, I need to forward the same request to a downstream service with exactly same URL (including root context and all the rest of the headers, query parameters and URL parameters properties).

I have tried to implement this using Rest Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/**")
public String validate(
            @RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParameters,
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
   // validate headers
   // validate body
   // validate URL parameters
   // validate query parameters

   forwardRequest()
}
```

Here implementing forwardRequest, I am trying to use a restTemplate and setting all the properties and making an exchange() call. However I am thinking there must be a better way to forward the request as is without handcrafting the request using RestTemplate.
Any suggestions?

Comment: did you find a solution? take a look at Zuul from netflix

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the fact that there is concept called `HandlerInterceptor`.

Step 1:

```
public class ValidationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
  private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ValidationInterceptor.class);
  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {
    // validate headers
   // validate body
   // validate URL parameters
   // validate query parameters
    return true;//forwardRequest(); False will break the chain.
  }
}
```

Step 2:

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new ValidationInterceptor())
    .addPathPatterns("/*", "/*.html");//Add as many as patterns you want this validator to be called!
  }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of the interceptors. This still does not resolve the issue of 'forwarding' the request to an upstream system without hand crafting the entire HTTP request.
Bare in mind that the upstream system sits in a different network tier and I won't be able to add a validation interceptor in the upstream application.

Comment: Do you mean to say you are proxying the requests?

Comment: Yes, based on the Validation I would have to reject or forward/proxy the request.